# TypeError: string indices must be integers pandas when replacing dataframe using dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe

i ran this code to replace the values of the pandas dataframe using dicitonary in python 3

```
  dict= { 1:0 , 2:0.4 , 3:0.8 , 4:1.2 , 5:1.6 , 6:2.0 , 7:2.4 , 8:2.8 , 9:3.2 , 10:3.8 , 11:4.0 }
    traindata["FamilySize"].replace(dict, inplace=True)
```

but it gave me this error -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-213-c213b2e1560f> in <module>
      1 dict= {1:0, 2:0.4, 3:0.8, 4:1.2, 5:1.6, 6:2.0, 7:2.4, 8:2.8, 9:3.2, 10:3.8, 11:4.0}
----> 2 traindata["FamilySize"].replace(dict, inplace=True)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

what should i do ?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are the only possible values in `range(0,11)`? Looks like you could instead do `traindata["FamilySize"].sub(1).mul(0.4)`

Comment: Can you show the `traindata['FamilySize'].head()`?